# Why does the TLS heartbeat extension allow user supplied data?

Tags: ssl, heartbleed-bug

The heartbeat protocol requires the other end to reply with the same data that was sent to it, to know that the other end is alive. Wouldn't sending a certain fixed message be simpler? Is it to prevent some kind of attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least the size of the packet seems to be relevant, because according to RFC6520, 5.1 the heartbeat message will be used with DTLS (e.g. TLS over UDP) for PMTU discovery - in which cases it needs messages of different sizes. Apart from that it might be simply modelled after ICMP ping, where you can also specify the payload content for no reason.

Comment: But even for dtls, as long as the message size is small enough to fit in the datagram packet, it would wouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: The idea of PMTU discovery is that you send packets which different sizes to find out how much payload you can put into the packet before it gets dropped or fragmented, e.g to find out how big in can be to be still "small enough to fit". Sure you could always send packets with only 563 bytes payload (576 minimal guaranteed size without fragmenting minus 13 bytes DTLS framing) but this would be a waste.

Answer (score 1):

Just like with ICMP Ping, the idea is to ensure you can match up a "pong" heartbeat response you received with whichever "ping" heartbeat request you made. Some packets may get lost or arrive out of order and if you send the requests fast enough and all the response contents are the same, there's no way to tell which of your requests were answered.

One might think, "WHO CARES? I just got a response; therefore, the other side is alive and well, ready to do my bidding :D!" But what if the response was actually for a heartbeat request 10 minutes ago (an extreme case, maybe due to the server being overloaded)? If you just sent another heartbeat request a few seconds ago and the expected responses are the same for all (a "fixed message"), then you would have no way to tell the difference.

A timely response is important in determining the health of the connection. From [RFC6520](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6520) page 3:

> ... after a number of retransmissions without
> receiving a **corresponding** HeartbeatResponse message having the
> expected payload, the DTLS connection SHOULD be terminated.

By allowing the requester to specify the return payload (and assuming the requester always generates a unique payload), the requester can match up a heartbeat response to a particular heartbeat request made, and therefore be able to calculate the round-trip time, expiring the connection if appropriate.

This of course only makes much sense if you are using TLS over a non-reliable protocol like UDP instead of TCP.

---

#### So why allow the requester to specify the length of the payload? Couldn't it be inferred?

See this excellent answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/55608/44094

> ... seems to be part of an attempt at genericity and coherence. In the SSL/TLS standard, all messages follow regular encoding rules, using a specific presentation language. No part of the protocol "infers" length from the record length.
>
> One gain of not inferring length from the outer structure is that it makes it much easier to include optional extensions afterwards. This was done with ClientHello messages, for instance.

In short, **YES**, it could've been, but for consistency with existing format and for future proofing, the size is spec'd out so that other data can follow the same message.